# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (11253,1) into shape (11253)

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am creating a Neural Network using this [example](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-with-deep-learning-in-python-with-keras/) and I am getting the error "ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (11253,1)" into shape (11253), in the line : `trainPredictPlot[look_back:len(trainPredict)+look_back] = trainPredicty` My code is:

```
import csv
import math
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X1 = [1:16801] #16,800 values
Y1 = [1:16801]#16,800 values

train_size = int(len(X1) * 0.67)
test_size = len(X1) - train_size

train, test = X1[0:train_size,], X1[train_size:len(X1),]
def Data(X1, look_back=1):
     dataX, dataY = [], []
     for i in range(len(X1)-look_back-1):
         a = X1[i:(i+look_back), 0]
         dataX.append(a)
         dataY.append(Y1[i + look_back, 0])
     return numpy.array(dataX), numpy.array(dataY)

look_back = 1
trainX, testX = Data(train, look_back)

testX, testY = Data(test, look_back)

look_back = 1
trainX, testX = Data(train, look_back)

testX, testY = Data(test, look_back)


trainPredict = model.predict(trainX)
testPredict = model.predict(testX)

trainPredictPlot = numpy.empty_like(Y1)
trainPredictPlot[look_back:len(trainPredict)+look_back] = trainPredict

testPredictPlot = numpy.empty_like(Y1) 
testPredictPlot[len(trainPredict)+(look_back*2)+1:len(X1)-1] = testPredict
```

I have 16,800 values for X1 which look like:

```
[0.03454225 0.02062136 0.00186715 ... 0.92857565 0.64930691 0.20325924]
```

And my Y1 data looks like:

```
[ 2.25226244  1.44078451  0.99174488 ... 12.8397099   9.75722427 7.98525797]
```

My traceback error message is:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-e4da8990335b> in <module>()
    116 trainPredictPlot = numpy.empty_like(Y1)
    117 
--> 118 trainPredictPlot[look_back:len(trainPredict)+look_back] = trainPredict
    119 
    120 testPredictPlot = numpy.empty_like(Y1)

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (11253,1) into shape (11253)
```

Comment: did you try searching? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=numpy+could+not+broadcast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `trainPredict` from 2D array to 1D vector before assigning:

```
trainPredictPlot[look_back:len(trainPredict)+look_back] = trainPredict.ravel()
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, I am still getting the same error as before

Comment: @Asif.Khan, what is the output of `print(type(trainPredict)); print(trainPredict.shape)`

Comment: the output for the type is: "class 'numpy.ndarray'>"  and the shape is:(11253, 1)

Comment: Thank you this has worked, but I am now but I am getting the same error in the line "testPredictPlot[len(trainPredict)+(look_back*2)+1:len(X1)-1] = testPredict". The outputs are: "class 'numpy.ndarray'>" and the shape is:(5542, 1) .   If i try with the .ravel () I get a long error message with "ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1" at the end? Would it be possible to get help with this too?

Comment: @Asif.Khan, can you provide a small __reproducible__ data set? So that we could reproduce this error...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176017/discussion-between-asif-khan-and-maxu).

Comment: I have added the reproducible dataset in the chat